# javafx snapshot with slow performance

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a basic space real time strategy game that needs a very large map, but will only show a small part of the map at a time. I have found that this is very easy to do with a viewport using imageview. Unfortunately, imageview needs an image to be passed to it and I have been using a canvas to draw all the sprites onto the background. I have been using snapshot to take an image of the fully rendered scene and passing that to imageview so I can use a viewport, but that has been causing a severe drop in performance. Without the use of snapshot, the game runs at 60+ fps, however when using snapshot the fps is always 15 or lower. Using snapshot was not a problem when the scene was 1024x512, but the scene is now 4096x2048. Is there a better way to use imageview and viewport 60 times a second without using snapshot? Example code of what I'm doing below:

```
    Group trueRoot = new Group(); //shown image
    Group root = new Group(); //invisible unedited image

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(4096, 2048); //unedited canvas
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    Scene scene2 = new Scene(trueRoot);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene2);

    WritableImage sceneImage = root.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null); //snapshot of fully rendered root scene
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(sceneImage); //imageView can be used to resize or crop
    Rectangle2D viewportRect = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, 1024, 512); //for cropping
    imageView.setViewport(viewportRect); //for cropping
    trueRoot.getChildren().add(imageView); //also for resizing / cropping

    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) { 

                //simple animated background
                if (cloudTimer == 16384)
                    cloudTimer = 0;
                else
                    cloudTimer++;

                gc.drawImage(stars, 0, 0);
                gc.drawImage(clouds1, cloudTimer % 16384, 0);
                gc.drawImage(clouds1, (cloudTimer % 16384) - 8192, 0);
                gc.drawImage(clouds2, (cloudTimer / 2) % 16384, 0);
                gc.drawImage(clouds2, ((cloudTimer / 2) % 16384) - 8192, 0);

                p1.update(p2, root);
                p2.update(p1, root);
                p1.render(gc, root);
                p2.render(gc, root);

                root.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), sceneImage); //takes root scene and hands it to trueRoot
        }
    }.start();


    primaryStage.show();
```

full code at https://github.com/WiredOverload/ObliterateEverything

I know that I could use asynchronous snapshot to avoid delaying the rest of the code while the snapshot is taking place, but that would still leave the game at 15 fps. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own `viewport` property with a listener that adjusts the `GraphicsContext`'s transform to apply a transform & scale that fits the viewport to the `Canvas`'s size:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    GraphicsContext context = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    ObjectProperty<Rectangle2D> viewport = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Rectangle2D.EMPTY);
    Pane root = new Pane(canvas);
    root.setPrefSize(400, 400);
    canvas.setManaged(false);
    root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldBound, newBounds) -> {
        canvas.setWidth(newBounds.getWidth());
        canvas.setHeight(newBounds.getHeight());
        Rectangle2D vp = viewport.get();
        viewport.set(new Rectangle2D(vp.getMinX(), vp.getMinY(), newBounds.getWidth(), newBounds.getHeight()));
    });

    viewport.addListener((observable, oldViewport, newViewport) -> {
        // combined transform & scale transfromation
        context.setTransform(canvas.getWidth() / newViewport.getWidth(), 0,
                0, canvas.getHeight() / newViewport.getHeight(),
                -newViewport.getMinX(), -newViewport.getMinY());
        redraw(context);
    });


    // sample movement animation
    Transition scale = new Transition() {

        {
            setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
            setCycleCount(2);
            setAutoReverse(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void interpolate(double frac) {
            double scale = 1 + 2 * frac;
            Rectangle2D vp = viewport.get();
            viewport.set(new Rectangle2D(vp.getMinX(), vp.getMinY(), canvas.getWidth() / scale, canvas.getHeight() / scale));
        }

    };

    Transition move = new Transition() {

        {
            setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
            setCycleCount(2);
            setAutoReverse(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void interpolate(double frac) {
            double posX = 300 * frac;
            Rectangle2D vp = viewport.get();
            viewport.set(new Rectangle2D(posX, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()));
        }

    };

    SequentialTransition animation = new SequentialTransition(scale, move);
    animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private static Color[] colors = new Color[]{
    Color.RED,
    Color.BEIGE,
    Color.GREEN,
    Color.ORANGE,
    Color.BLACK,
    Color.BLUE,
    Color.WHEAT,
    Color.CORAL,
    Color.CRIMSON,
    Color.PURPLE,
    Color.AQUAMARINE,
    Color.YELLOW,
    Color.CHOCOLATE
};

public static void redraw(GraphicsContext gc) {
    Bounds bounds;
    try {
        bounds = gc.getTransform().inverseTransform(gc.getCanvas().getLayoutBounds());
    } catch (NonInvertibleTransformException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    gc.clearRect(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        gc.setFill(colors[i]);
        gc.fillRect(i * 50, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement this into my code. If I can manage to put it in correctly I'll say whether it worked or not.